# Adding arrow to menu item with child in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to add a down arrow to a menu item with a child. It should appear on the Our Story nav item on this site: http://www.estiponagroup.com/

If I inspect the element it shows in the CSS but it doesn't show in the menu. What can I do to actually make it show up?

CSS:

```
.main-header.menu-type-standard-menu .standard-menu-container.menu-skin-main ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a::after {
    color: #ccc;
    content: '\25BC'; /*Down arrow*/
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class="main-header menu-type-standard-menu">
    <div class="container">     
        <div class="menu-column">
            <div class="standard-menu-container  menu-skin-main reveal-from-top">
                <nav>
                    <ul class="menu" id="menu-main-nav-1">
                        <!-- Other Menu Items are Here -->
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-649"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/our-story/" data-slimstat-tracking="false" data-slimstat-callback="true" data-slimstat-type="2">Our Story</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1593"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/virtual-office-vs-traditional-office/" data-slimstat-tracking="false" data-slimstat-callback="true" data-slimstat-type="2">Virtual vs Traditional</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-650"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/news/" data-slimstat-tracking="false" data-slimstat-callback="true" data-slimstat-type="2">News</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-651"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/our-fans/" data-slimstat-tracking="false" data-slimstat-callback="true" data-slimstat-type="2">Fans</a></li>
                        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-652"><a href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/contact/" data-slimstat-tracking="false" data-slimstat-callback="true" data-slimstat-type="2">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to play with it to get it where you want, but it's padding your after.  You'll need to add some both to the `<a>` element as well as the `::after`.  `padding: 21px 14px;` for the `::after` and `padding: 0 33px;` for the anchor seems like a good start.

Comment: Now the problem is that it is styled from the left to right. Meaning that I had to set the padding to: padding: 20px 12px 20px 93px !important;

The arrow shows to the right of this menu item based on 93px. If I add another submenu to a parent nav item that is shorter or longer it won't always appear just to the right of the text. I want the arrow to appear after the menu item, always the same distance. How can I make sure it always aligns to the right instead of the left?

Comment: Any reason it needs to be an `::after` element?  You might be better off just adding it as a plain character and find it easier to style.